# what you know 'bout rockin' a wolf on your noggin?

Tags: meaning

I've decided to watch some rap music that I used to listen to back in times when I was teenager, and the last night while listening *thrift shop* by macklemore, I encountered to this quite bizarre idiom up in the title. Have searched for it on the web, forums and examined word after word etc. etc. but it didn't help me. I know its a rap music, people tend to tangle words using slangy expressions that don't even take place in literature and come up with rigged up definitions so its quite nonsense looking for a meaning(*just let it be*) but it really beats me at the moment, not knowing what does that refer to.

Comment: Please include the phrase that you are asking about in the body of your question, and do not delete your question once answered. Questions and answers are meant to be a resource.

Comment: You could clean up your question by: properly capitalizing the name of the song and the band. Also, "it's", don't, not knowing what that refers to, have searched for it on the web.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what Michael Harvey said, "noggin" *is* slang for head, and to "rock" can mean to wear with style.

But, being aware of "coonskin caps" and given the nearby "wearing a fur fox skin", since the line says *on* your noggin, I suspect Macklemore is talking about finding some sort of wolf hat (an odd item likely to be donated since it's hard to think of where most people would wear one) at a thrift store and wearing it with aplomb. The "What [do] you know 'bout..." part acknowledges that this wouldn't be a common experience considering, again, that most people don't often wear wolf hats.

As a whole I'm not sure I would consider this an idiom; I've never heard the whole phrase before outside the song, and most search results for "rocking a wolf on your noggin" seem to be references to the song.

(I wondered about a nod perhaps, to all the animal headpieces in "What Does the Fox Say?", but "Thrift Shop" came out before "The Fox".)

Comment: There's no reason a vintage fur hat couldn't be made of wolf fur as easily as any other sort of fur. It doesn't have to look like a wolf head. Macklemore's love of vintage fur clothing is well-known.

Comment: The song is all about finding weird things to wear at a Thrift Shop. He talks about finding alligator shoes and a fox fur coat. So yeah, he probably means a hat made out of wolf fur. Maybe, possibly, a wolf mask or a hat made to look like a wolf, but that wouldn't really fit in with the other things in the song. So probably a wolf fur hat.

Answer (score 1):

The song is said to be about about finding weird things to wear at a thrift shop. (low-priced US used-items shop) To 'rock' can mean to wear (clothes), or adopt (an attitude, fashion), etc. A 'noggin' is slang for a person's head or mind. To rock a wolf on your noggin would suggest perhaps wearing a wolf mask, or wolfskin hat, or maybe figuratively acting in a wolflike manner.

[Rock (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rock)

[Noggin (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/noggin)